# Retrieving values from a PHP page, outside a form, to query MSSQL?

Tags: php, sql-server, ajax, forms

I know the question title may be confusing, but here is what I am trying to achieve:

I have a UL within a table filled with many items. One of the cells of the list contains a checkbox. Those checkboxes are all named in an array "itemsDone[]" I have a button in a side menu (outside of a form). I would like this button to send a query to my server to update a value for each checkbox that is checked... is it possible? I've been Googling for roughly an hour, and I may be seeking the wrong keywords... I would appreciate any help given.

Thank you guys and have a nice day!

Edit: There are no forms at all inside the PHP page.

Edit2: Here is the code I now have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#saveCheckboxes").click(function(){
        var check = Array();
        var counter= 0;

        $('.itemsDone').each(function(){
            if(this.checked)
            {
                check[counter] = this.value;
                counter+=1;
                console.log(check[counter]);
            }
        })

        $.post('setCommandes.php',{'check[]':check}, function(data) {

            alert(data);

        });      
       return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Here is my setCommandes.php content:

```
<?php
    include('includes/connexion.php');
    $data = $_POST['check[]'];

    $db_select=mssql_select_db("Test_CommandesWeb");
    foreach ($data as $checks)
    {
        $sql = "UPDATE Commandes SET CommandeFaite='1' WHERE CommandeId='$checks'";
        mssql_query($sql,$connexion);
    }
?>
```

I am getting an error (Invalid argument supplied) on my foreach statement at the moment.

Comment: Change $data = $_POST['check[]']; to $data = $_POST['check'];

Comment: Thanks, I got it. I also has to change the $('.itemsDone').each(function() for $('[name=itemsDone\ \[\ \]]').each(function() since I am using the 'name' attribute (sigh). Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this using [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

I'm not sure about what your page looks like but I guess the code would be something like this:

---

//make sure to use the a proper [selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

```
//so, do the following when .class is clicked
$(".class").click(function(){

    //select the value 
    $('select.foo').val();

    //post the data
    $.post('ajax/test.html', function(data) {

        //replace the .result div with the
        //response from the server
        $('.result').html(data);

    });      

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do that with jQuery, something like this:

```
$('#myButton').click(function(){

    // loop through all checkboxes and check if they're checked
    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
       if (this.checked) {
           // do something with the checkbox if it's checked, like make ajax call
    });

});
```

Or, you could do it with PHP.  Just put your submit button inside of the form and when the submit, access the array itemsDone[] and see if it's checked.

Answer (score 0):

Buttons must be within a form to submit them. Your form should hold all the inputs you want along with the button.

```
<form method="POST" action="/mark_items_done.php">

  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" name="itemsDone[]" value="1" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" name="itemsDone[]" value="2" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" name="itemsDone[]" value="3" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" name="itemsDone[]" value="4" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" name="itemsDone[]" value="5" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" name="itemsDone[]" value="6" />
    </li>
  </ul>

  <input type="submit" value="Send Items" />
</form>
```

On your PHP page you can get the `itemsDone` with.

```
<?php

$items_done = isset($_POST['itemsDone']) ? $_POST['itemsDone'] : null;

if( $items_done ) {
  // do something with the items
}
```

---

If you don't want to move the button inside the form you can do something like this with jQuery.

```
$('#submit_button').click(function() {
  $('#my_form').submit();
});
```

This solution will reload the page, but it shouldn't be too difficult to implement AJAX if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the next steps:

1) You can submit any form by any action using javascript.
In this case your form must contain attributes name or id:

Form itself:

```
<form name="formName" id="formId" method="POST" action="anyformhandler.php">
<input type="checkbox" value="opt1" name="itemsDone[]">
<input type="checkbox" value "opt2" name="itemsDone[]">
</form>
```

Submitter outside form (for example simple text):

```
<a href="#" onClick="document.formName.submit()">Submit the form!</a>
```

or

```
<a href="#" onClick="document.forms['formId'].submit()">Submit the form!</a>
```

2) In a php file, that handles the form get the data:

```
  if ((isset($_POST["itemsDone"])) and (is_array($_POST["itemsDone"]))){
     // just do needed stuff.
    }
```

3) To update the values for each checkbox when using a database, you should interact with the database. query to database -> store the data -> load the values of your checkboxes.

Ask questions if you you would like to. Hope this helps ;)